# In PowerShell, how can I determine if the DNS server I'm using, is a domain controller?

Tags: powershell, dns, domaincontroller

I want to make sure, that the DNS server I use, is a domain controller. I know the domain name. Can I check that with PowerShell? Such as to resolve some DC specified DNS record:

```
Resolve-DnsName -Name '_tcp.'+$DomainName
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of all name servers of a domain with:

```
Resolve-DnsName -Name $env:USERDNSDOMAIN -Type NS
```

And you can get a list of all domain controllers of a domain with:

```
Resolve-DnsName -Name _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.$env:USERDNSDOMAIN -Type SRV
```

To get a list of all domain controllers that are also DNS servers (which is most probably the case nowadays), you can execute the following code:

```
$dnsServers = (Resolve-DnsName -Name $env:USERDNSDOMAIN -Type NS).NameHost
Resolve-DnsName -Name _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.$env:USERDNSDOMAIN -Type SRV | Where-Object {$_.NameTarget -in $dnsServers}
```

Then you can check, if the list contains the DNS server you are using.